# Aggregate Pandas DataFrame with condition using NamedAgg

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have an orders table with column order_state. And need to count orders for each order state, grouped by hour, but not using group by order_state column. And I want to use NamedAgg. Is it possible? Something like this:

```
orders_agg = orders.groupby(
    by=[pandas.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='H'), 'source']
).agg(
    orders_count=pandas.NamedAgg('created_at', 'count'),
    finished_orders_count=pandas.NamedAgg('order_state', lambda x: (x == 'finished').count()),
    cancelled_orders_count=pandas.NamedAgg('order_state', lambda x: (x == 'offer_cancelled').count())
).reset_index().rename(columns={'created_at': 'datetime_msk'})
```

And result should be:
[image]
But now i get total orders count in each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need change `.count()` to `.sum()` for count `True`s values:

```
orders_agg = orders.groupby(
by=[pandas.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='H'), 'source']
).agg(
orders_count=pandas.NamedAgg('created_at', 'count'),
finished_orders_count=pandas.NamedAgg('order_state', lambda x: x == 'finished').sum(),
    cancelled_orders_count=pandas.NamedAgg('order_state', lambda x: (x == 'offer_cancelled').sum())
).reset_index().rename(columns={'created_at': 'datetime_msk'})
```